# Divide by zero error when Perfoming a percentage (Divisor from unjoined table with date parameters)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to get a percentage of number of times a product is faulty.
I have the faults in one table and the throughput in another. Throughput could never be 0. The report would never be ran if it was 0.
Unfortunately the tables cannot be joined.
I can get the correct result returned in SQL but when I apply the query to manufacturing software with date parameters applied I receive the divide by 0 error.

Query working in SQL:

```
SELECT  
CAST (COUNT (faulttype.faults) AS FLOAT)/
CAST ((SELECT COUNT(throughput.throughput)
FROM [throughput]
WHERE throughput.throughput   >= '2017-08-08 00:00:00' and throughput.throughput  <= '2018-08-13 23:59:00') 
AS FLOAT)
*100 Percentage

FROM faults (nolock)

INNER JOIN faulttype (nolock) ON faults = faults.faults

where fault.procedure = 15 
and  faults.regtime   >= '2017-08-08 00:00:00' and qc_inspections.regtime <= '2018-08-13 23:59:00'
```

Query with date parameters applied (receives divide by 0 error):

```
SELECT  
CAST (COUNT (faulttype.fault) AS FLOAT)/
CAST ((SELECT COUNT(throughput.throughput)
FROM [throughput]
WHERE CAST(faultype.regtime as date) between @datetimerange_From and @datetimerange_To
AS FLOAT)
  *100 Percentage

FROM faults (nolock)

   INNER JOIN faulttype (nolock) ON faults.id = faulttype.fault

   where fault.procedure = 15 
   and  CAST(faults.regtime as date) between @datetimerange_From and @datetimerange_To
```

I have tried nullif and also case statement to no avail. Case statement didn't work because of lack of join. I managed to fudge something together so that the case statement searched for an ID count of 1 then show one (that it would never be) else perform my division. I thought it would trick SQL into not seeing a 0 prior to the user applying the date parameters. Buuuut that didn't work and I am sure somebody will tell me why lol.

Comment: But you are comparing different columns between the two queries, `throughput.throughput` in the first and `faultype.regtime` in the second?

Comment: Just wrap it within a case and return a 0 or null when the divisor is 0. It has to work, show us the case statement and nullif that you have tried.

Comment: Side note - unless you're deliberately trying to exclude events during the last minute of each day, use an *exclusive* endpoint - `throughput  < '20180814'`. You'll also note that the exclusive endpoint is always correct no matter what `datetime` datatype (with varied precision possibilities) is in use.

Answer (score 0):

Its Strange you dont have join on [throughput]
 table, but if i take your query like it, try Something like this:

```
with CountFault as (
select count(throughput) CountFault 
from [throughput]
where  CAST(throughput as date) between @datetimerange_From and @datetimerange_To
)
select count(f2.fault as decimal) / nullif(f3.CountFault, 0) * 100
from faults f1
INNER JOIN faulttype f2 ON f1.id = f2.fault
cross join CountFault f3
where f1.procedure = 15 and  CAST(f1.regtime as date) between @datetimerange_From and @datetimerange_To
```